# Notify Other user about video being disabled: TokBox

Tags: ios, swift, tokbox

In TokBox SDK for Video calling, if one user disables his/her video, how other user will get notified?

Answer (score 1):

TokBox Developer Evangelist here.

For iOS, you can use the OTSubscriberKit Delegate and implement the following method: `subscriberVideoDisabled:reason:`

After you've set the delegate, you can implement something like this in Swift:

`func subscriberVideoDisabled(_ subscriber: OTSubscriberKit, reason: OTSubscriberVideoEventReason) {
// handle reason
  }`

Here are the docs that explain the different reasons: https://tokbox.com/developer/sdks/ios/reference/Constants/OTSubscriberVideoEventReason.html